# Nuxt static website not generating body content

Tags: nuxt.js

Generated the project using `nuxt generate` and created the routes for `_slug` pages this way:

```
 generate: {
      routes() {
        return axios.get('https://mywebsite.xyz/categories').then(res => {
          return res.data.data.map(category => {
           return '/collections/' + category.id
         })
      })
    },
  },
```

The routes are generated fine but the body is empty, can be checked here: [Website Link](https://flowerqueen.ro/collections/cutie-cu-flori-si-dulciuri)

my nuxt.config:

```
 export default {
   ssr: false,
   target: 'static',

     router: {
     base: '/',
     extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
         routes.push({
            path: '/collections/:slug',
            components: {
               default: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/collections'), // or routes[index].component
            },
           chunkNames: {
              modal: 'components/modal'
           }
       })
     },
   },
```

How to generate the body to be exactly the same as an html website?

P.S Forgot to mention one important thing. I am using `async fetch` to load the data:

```
 async fetch() {
     this.filters.category = this.$route.params.slug;
     await this.$store.dispatch('filter/getProducts',
        { Product: Product.filter(this.filters)
     });
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `nuxt generate` the webpack create a static files kind of like an SPA but with more details the dynamic content like the section product sorting is probably from an API so this will not be rendered

### Fix 1

Try using Heroku or vercel to host this application or any node server so that the data is pre-populated before sending

### Fix 2

Use `asyncData` to get and populate the data before sending it to the user

```js
export default {
  async asyncData(context) {
    const id = context.params.id
    try {
      // Using the nuxtjs/http module here exposed via context.app
      const post = await context.app.$http.$get(
        `https://api.nuxtjs.dev/posts/${id}`
      )
      return { post }
    } catch (e) {
      context.error(e) // Show the nuxt error page with the thrown error
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If he is using `nuxt generate`, no need for a node hosted solution, a CDN like Netlify is totally fine. AsyncData could be a solution but it lacks the main thing here: SEO.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not using Heroku as VPS but my hosting has exactly the same parameters. The problem is in the way I build the app. Regarding async, all the actions/calls are made this way.

Comment: Is this a dynamic route ??

Comment: In some places I have dynamic routes <nuxt-link in other I have just <a href, it is what you meant by dynamic route?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: just to be clear, for dev you can run

- `nuxt` or `nuxt dev` (alias)

For local testing of your full static app, you can do:

- `nuxt generate`
- `nuxt start`
- (`nuxt serve` is actually deprecated, if it's not, double check that
  you have the `2.14.X` or `2.15.0` version installed for Nuxt)

For local testing of your **NON** static app (`target: server`), aka SSR only

- `nuxt build`
- `nuxt start`

For the directories, `.nuxt` is essentially a local built + cached version of webpack for development purposes. `dist` is the one that you will point as the entry point of your app for pretty much every target (in production).

`nuxt build` is if you want to build the project in an SSR only way, aka this will require NodeJS to be present.
`nuxt generate` can allow you to dump files on Github pages, without any server.
More details on those commands [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/get-started/commands/).

Also, I guess that you bought a VPS or alike and that you try to setup the whole app to run with nginx and so on ? I will not be able to help you here, and it should be part of another question btw.

But right now, I do recommend that you try to `generate` the app locally and double check that everything is fine (it should be !). Then, I cannot stress enough to use a platform like [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) or [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/). I'm not sponsored or anything, their platform is just too dope to not use. It will provide you awesome performance, make things super easy, you'll be able to plug some [Netlify] plugins easily and...it's free (static hosting is not hard to host, like Github Pages).

There is actually a whole section on [deployment](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/netlify-deployment) on the official docs. I definitely recommend those solutions (static hosting platform) since they will be easier to setup/deploy, less expensive than a VPS, eco-friendly and with more features out of the box. It's the main point of JAMstack actually.

---

---

You have `ssr: false`, your app cannot generate the content if you explicity tell it to **only** generate your app on your client. If you want to have an isomorphic or *universal* app that works both on server beforehead (SEO) and still have benefits from an SPA (thanks to hydration), you need to remove this line or set it to `true`.

More details can be found on the official [`ssr` property page](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-mode).

Server side rendering will only be used during `dev` and build time (`nuxt generate`), then it will be uploadable to any CDN. But right now, if you go to your hosted website and disable the JS, you will see a blank page.

Or you can inspect your source code by pressing `ctrl + u` and you'll see that your current app is rendered **only** on the client. That explains why you cannot generate those routes (because it's an operation done during the node build time).

Btw, I'm not sure exactly of how your app works but if you did your pages properly, you may even not need to make the routes yourself since Nuxt [integrates a crawler](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/going-full-static/#crawler-integrated) out of the box now.

[image]

---

TLDR: set back `ssr` boolean to `true` and inspect your app again (source code or disable the JS) to see your static content generated. Pretty much like any [nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/going-full-static) webpage.

Comment: I have changed the nuxt.config to ssr:true but the website is still not loaded statically. I am using nginx, npm, pm2 for running the website and ubuntu 20 server. What are the commands to generate static pages on the server?

Comment: Here is how I generate it:
npx nuxt build
npx nuxt generate
npx nuxt serve #serve is only for test, normally I am using pm2 reload but even with serve it's not displaying the html of the pages :(

Comment: This is working but only for index page, thank you :D But, when I check the /dist folder I could see all the pages generated staticly but when I access any of the pages by the url and press ctrl+u (google chrome) I can't see the content of the page, it empty body.

Comment: Is your code open source on github? Debugging like as of now is a nightmare for me.

Comment: check your email :)

Comment: After a lost day and almost weekend I am one step closer to the answer :) As I could see, the pages are not loaded staticly because is an error somewhere and I am redirected to /dist/200.html page as default redirect. This is the reason why index is loaded and other pages are not, now left to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 weeks of playing around with static pages, finally I have made it working.

I have tried all the recommendations from the authors from above and nothing was helping. In my case, the pages were generated statically but on `npm start` the project on `ctrl+u` ( chrome) as body had <Loading....> and then gtm tags.

As I found in nuxt documentation, I was seeing that page because I was always redirected to `200.html` or `404.html` because I had errors in my code and my `nuxt` was outdated (2.14.9).

After updating `nuxt` to `v2.15.3` and disabling javascript execution from chrome, I was able to see what was generating the redirects and errors. Nuxt template I have bought was not made for static projects and because of this, many things were crashing. I had to remove or re-build them.

If anyone in the future will struggle with the same problem, I recommend to:

1. Try the solution @kissu recommended.
2. Update nuxt to the latest version
3. Try to update other packages with `npm up`
4. Try installing `@nuxtjs/router` and test minimal amount of routes using `router.js`

Also if you just think to develop a `nuxt` static project, test how it generates and runs statically from the begging.

If you are using `async fetch` with vuex instead of `asyncData`, here is an example of a good static ecommerce project:

https://github.com/sdras/ecommerce-netlify

My actual nuxt.config:

```
   ssr: true,
   target: 'static',
   server: {
     port: 4000,
     host: 'localhost',
   },

   router: {
    base: '/',
    trailingSlash: true,
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also been struggling with the same problem for a while, and I can confirm that Alex St's solution works.

I updated Nuxt version from **2.14.6** to **2.15.4**, and Nuxt does not use spa mode for all the pages other than index any longer. All pages are now static HTML.

When updating Nuxt to 2.15, be advised to follow [Nuxt/components](https://github.com/nuxt/components) migration guide if you have components in subfolders (e.g. `./components/shared`).